# Should I Be Using Protocols for these Models?

Tags: swift-protocols

I am working with the Dribbble API, and there are three models that I am currently using:

- `User`
- `Team`
- `Shot`

A `Shot` is something that a `User` or `Team` uploads to their respective portfolio to be shown off. This can be an image or an animation. A `User` can belong to multiple `Team`s, while a `Team` can have multiple `User`s.

The three models each have many properties, which I have provided below.

`User` takes the following structure:

```swift
/// Encapsulates information about a Dribbble User.
public struct User {

    // MARK: - Properties

    /// The identifier of the User.
    public var identifier: Int?

    /// The name of the User.
    public var name: String?

    /// The username of the User.
    public var username: String?

    /// The `URL` for the User's Dribbble page.
    public var htmlURL: URL?

    /// The `URL` for the User's avatar image.
    public var avatarURL: URL?

    /// The biography for the User.
    public var biography: String?

    /// The location for the User.
    public var location: String?

    /// The `URL` for the User's website.
    public var websiteURL: URL?

    /// The `URL` for the User's Twitter profile.
    public var twitterURL: URL?

    /// The number of Buckets for the User.
    public var bucketsCount: Int?

    /// The number of Comments the User has received.
    public var commentsReceivedCount: Int?

    /// The number of followers for the User.
    public var followersCount: Int?

    /// The number of followings for the User.
    public var followingsCount: Int?

    /// The number of Likes for the User.
    public var likesCount: Int?

    /// The number of Likes received for the User.
    public var likesReceivedCount: Int?

    /// The number of projects for the User.
    public var projectsCount: Int?

    /// The number of Rebounds received for the User.
    public var reboundsReceivedCount: Int?

    /// The number of Shots for the User.
    public var shotsCount: Int?

    /// The number of Teams that the User belongs to.
    public var teamsCount: Int?

    /// Whether the User is authorized to upload Shots.
    public var canUploadShot: Bool?

    /// The type of User.
    public var type: String?

    /// Whether the User has Pro status.
    public var isPro: Bool?

    /// The `URL` for the User's Buckets.
    public var bucketsURL: URL?

    /// The `URL` for the User's followers.
    public var followersURL: URL?

    /// The `URL` for the User's followings.
    public var followingURL: URL?

    /// The `URL` for the User's Likes.
    public var likesURL: URL?

    /// The `URL` for the User's Projects.
    public var projectsURL: URL?

    /// The `URL` for the User's Shots.
    public var shotsURL: URL?

    /// The `URL` for the Teams that the User belongs to.
    public var teamsURL: URL?

    /// The `Date` that the User was created.
    public var createdAt: Date?

    /// The `Date` that the User was last updated.
    public var updatedAt: Date?
}
```

`Team` takes the following structure:

```swift
/// Encapsulates information about a Dribbble Team.
public struct Team {

    // MARK: - Properties

    /// The identifier of the Team.
    public var identifier: Int?

    /// The name of the Team.
    public var name: String?

    /// The username of the Team.
    public var username: String?

    /// the `URL` for the Team's Dribbble page.
    public var htmlURL: URL?

    /// The `URL` for the Team's avatar image.
    public var avatarURL: URL?

    /// The biography for the Team.
    public var biography: String?

    /// The location for the Team.
    public var location: String?

    /// The `URL` for the Team's website.
    public var websiteURL: URL?

    /// The `URL` for the Team's Twitter profile.
    public var twitterURL: URL?

    /// The number of Buckets for the Team.
    public var bucketsCount: Int?

    /// The number of Comments the Team has received.
    public var commentsReceivedCount: Int?

    /// The number of followers for the Team.
    public var followersCount: Int?

    /// The number of followings for the Team.
    public var followingsCount: Int?

    /// The number of Likes for the Team.
    public var likesCount: Int?

    /// The number of Likes received for the Team.
    public var likesReceivedCount: Int?

    /// The number of projects for the Team.
    public var projectsCount: Int?

    /// The number of Rebounds received for the Team.
    public var reboundsReceivedCount: Int?

    /// The number of Shots for the Team.
    public var shotsCount: Int?

    /// Whether the Team is authorized to upload Shots.
    public var canUploadShot: Bool?

    /// The type of Team.
    public var type: String?

    /// Whether the Team has Pro status.
    public var isPro: Bool?

    /// The `URL` for the Team's Buckets.
    public var bucketsURL: URL?

    /// The `URL` for the Team's followers.
    public var followersURL: URL?

    /// The `URL` for the Team's followings.
    public var followingURL: URL?

    /// The `URL` for the Team's Likes.
    public var likesURL: URL?

    /// The `URL` for the Team's Projects.
    public var projectsURL: URL?

    /// The `URL` for the Team's Shots.
    public var shotsURL: URL?

    /// The `Date` that the Team was created.
    public var createdAt: Date?

    /// The `Date` that the Team was last updated.
    public var updatedAt: Date?

    /// The number of members for the Team.
    public var membersCount: Int?

    /// The `URL` for the members of the Team.
    public var membersURL: URL?

    /// The `URL` for the Team Shots.
    public var teamShotsURL: URL?

}
```

`Shot` takes the following structure:

```swift
/// Encapsulates information about a Dribbble Shot.
public struct Shot {

    // MARK: - Properties

    /// The identifier of the Shot.
    public var identifier: Int?

    /// The title of the Shot.
    public var title: String?

    /// The description of the Shot.
    public var description: String?

    /// The size of the Shot.
    public var size: CGSize?

    /// The `URL` for the Shot's high-definition image.
    public var highDefinitionImageURL: URL?

    /// The `URL` for the Shot's normal image.
    public var normalImageURL: URL?

    /// The `URL` for the Shot's teaser image.
    public var teaserImageURL: URL?

    /// The number of views for the Shot.
    public var viewsCount: Int?

    /// The number of likes for the Shot.
    public var likesCount: Int?

    /// The number of comments for the Shot.
    public var commentsCount: Int?

    /// The number of attachments for the Shot.
    public var attachmentsCount: Int?

    /// The number of Rebounds for the Shot.
    public var reboundsCount: Int?

    /// The number of Buckets for the Shot.
    public var bucketsCount: Int?

    /// The `Date` that the Shot was created.
    public var createdAt: Date?

    /// The `Date` that the Shot was last updated.
    public var updatedAt: Date?

    /// The `URL` for the Shot's Dribbble page.
    public var htmlURL: URL?

    /// The `URL` for the Shot's attachments.
    public var attachmentsURL: URL?

    /// The `URL` for the Shot's Buckets.
    public var bucketsURL: URL?

    /// The `URL` for the Shot's comments.
    public var commentsURL: URL?

    /// The `URL` for the Shot's Likes.
    public var likesURL: URL?

    /// The `URL` for the Shot's Projects.
    public var projectsURL: URL?

    /// The `URL` for the Shot's Rebounds.
    public var reboundsURL: URL?

    /// Whether the Shot is animated.
    public var isAnimated: Bool?

    /// The tags associated with the Shot.
    public var tags: Array<String>?

    /// The `User` that the Shot belongs to.
    public var user: User?

    /// The `team` that she Shot belongs to.
    public var team: Team?

}
```

`User` and `Team` have many duplicated properties, while `Shot` has a few that `User` and `Team` have. If I take the protocol route for these models, there will be *many* protocol implementations.

In my case, I have no reason to have an `Array` of `Identifiable` types or `WebsiteURL` types, or any other type that conforms to a protocol for the duplicated properties. I will have an `Array` of `Shot`s, which belong to either `User`s or `Team`s. I will also have `Array`s for `User`s and `Arrays` for `Team`s.

Should I implement protocols for the duplicated properties and have `User`, `Team`, and `Shot` conform to them, or would this lead to protocol hell for no apparent benefit other than being so-called "Swifty"?

Comment: What about using inheritance instead of protocol?

Comment: @HwanghoKim I thought about that, but if I wanted to have `Shot` inherit its duplicated properties as well, then the superclass would only have a few properties since `Shot` only has a few in common with `User` and `Team`. If I made a superclass for `User` and `Team` to inherit all of their duplicated properties, then `Shot` wouldn't be able to inherit from that superclass because of all of the extra properties that it doesn't need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what about using inheritance like this,

**Common parent** takes the properties Shot, User and Team have and **Parent for user and team** just take the properties only user and team have

```
   Common parent
     |
-----------------------------------------------
|                                             |
Parent for user and team                      |
|                                             |
|-----------|                                 |
User      Team                              Shot
```

Comment: I like this approach. It definitely simplifies the hierarchy. I don't know why I didn't think of this. I guess I've been thinking too deeply in a protocol-oriented state of mind.

Comment: Protocol would be the way but I think not matched perfectly for this case. ;)